# Freiling's question

Tags: measure-theory, set-theory

In his paper "Axioms of Symmetry: Throwing Darts at the Real Number Line," Freiling suggests two additional axioms that are formally analogous to his axiom of symmetry (which he proves to be equivalent to the negation of CH given ZFC):

- A-null: For any $f$ from the reals to *null* sets of reals (relative to the Lebesgue measure), there are $x,y$ such that $x\not\in f(y)$ and $y\not\in f(x)$
- A-meagre: For any $f$ from the reals to *meagre* sets of reals, there are $x,y$ such that $x\not\in f(y)$ and $y\not\in f(x)$.

Freiling says (p.194) he doesn't know whether A-null and A-meagre are jointly formally inconsistent (presumably given ZFC). Does anyone know if this question has already been answered? (I've made no progress on (dis)proving it myself...)

Comment: Now posted to MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/441396/freilings-question